# How to use selectattr with search on multiple strings

Tags: ansible

I have the following task where I search the attribute in a list of dictionary that should contain both the `unique_string1` and `unique_string2`.
This works, however, is it possible for me to merge the two `selectattr` statements into one?

```yaml
- set_fact:
    myvar: "{{ list.objects | selectattr('name', 'search', unique_string1)  | selectattr('name', 'search', unique_string2)  |  map(attribute='name') | last }}"
  vars:
    unique_string1: "yes"
    unique_string2: "no"
```

I thought I could use an `AND` (`AND` being placeholder for regex AND), something like:

```
selectattr('name', 'search', unique_string1 + 'AND' + unique_string2)
```

Comment: Did you try `(unique_string1|unique_string2)`

Comment: @Squashman `selectattr('name', 'search', '('~unique_string1~'|'~unique_string2~')')`, since those are variables.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε thanks for the correction.  Still learning Ansible and Jinja.  Our company just started using it a few months ago.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε, thanks for your answer. However, it doesn't filter the way I want to. It still includes data I don't want.

Comment: Probably because you are in a regex and "no" is so short it can match a lot, e.g. `normal` would be matched. Show us an example content of `list.objects` if you want a clearest answer.